# Need help in converting the for loop to list comprehension

Tags: python, pandas

need to import around 30 csv files to python , for that I have a for loop but I need to convert to list comprehension

The structure of all the files is same and they have same column names, out of all that I only need few of the columns as mentioned in the code and need to create one column which can differentiate the data

for Loop

```
import pandas as pd
cwd = os.getcwd()
dirs =os.listdir(cwd)

dfx=[]

for items in dirs:
    if items.find('GSVA')>0 and items.find('.csv')>0:
        x=cwd+'\\'+items
        temp_df=pd.read_csv((x),encoding = "ISO-8859-1")
        temp_df=temp_df.loc[::,['S.No.','Item','2014-15']]
        temp_df['State']=items.split('-')[1]
        dfx.append(temp_df)

gsva = pd.concat(dfx)
```

I have tried the below but not working

```
import os 
cwd = os.getcwd()
directory = os.listdir(cwd)

gsva = [(gsva.append(temp)
       temp['State']=items.split('-')[1]
       temp = temp.loc[::,['S.No.','Item','2014-15']]
       temp = pd.read_csv(cwd+'\\'+items)

       for items in directory
       if items.find('GSVA')>0 ]
gsva_1 = pd.concat(gsva)
```

Comment: Why do you **need** to convert the loop to a comprehension? It won't make the code any faster or more readable.

Comment: its a kind of task we are given , and as part of the task we need to use only list comprehension and not for loops

Comment: @meowgoesthedog is right. The result is going to be ugly and unreadable. Here our aim is to turn bad code into good code, not the other way around.

Comment: @boargules I do not think the result is going to be ugly and unreadable.

Comment: @naivepredictor I must admit you've done a workmanlike job. I still think the original is easier to read and easier to maintain, and that instructors should not be encouraging novices to write list comprehensions that implement procedural one-liners.

Answer (score 0):

```
import os
import pandas as pd

cwd = os.getcwd()

dirs = filter(lambda x: x[1]>=0 and x[2]>0, [(x, x.find('.csv'), x.find('GSVA')) for x in os.listdir(cwd)])
temp_df = [pd.read_csv((x),encoding = "ISO-8859-1") for x in [cwd+'\\'+x for x in dirs]]

def add_state(x):
    x['State'] = x.split('-')[1]
    return x

gsva = pd.concat(list(map(add_state, [temp_df.loc[::,['S.No.','Item','2014-15']] for x in temp_df])))
```

Comment: Hi Naivepredictor , thank you so much for the answer, but I am still getting the below error :(   
 6 dirs = filter(lambda x: x[1]>=0 and x[2]>0, [(x, x.find('.csv'), x.find('GSVA')) for x in os.listdir(cwd)])
----> 7 temp_df = [pd.read_csv((x),encoding = "ISO-8859-1") for x in [cwd+'\\'+x for x in dirs]]
      8 
      9 def add_state(x):

TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "tuple") to str